# Seperate rows in a dataframe based on custom value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with two columns `a` and `b`.

```py
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {'a': ['2019145236792', 'abc_def date_1220', '2020124832852', 'jhi_abc this_1219_abc'], 
            'b': ['tom','john','mark','jim']} 

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns=['a', 'b']) 
df
         a                        b
0      2019145236792             tom
1      abc_def date_1220        john
2      2020124832852            mark
3      jhi_abc this_1219_abc20   jim
```

I want to seperate the data which only contains `20`. The position of `20` won't change.

eg: `2020124832852` and `abc_def date_1220`

Expected output:

```py
          a                    b
0      abc_def date_1220    john
1      2020124832852        mark
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with comapre by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and indexing by `str` chained by `|` for bitwise `OR` by second mask with [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for values after `date_`:

```
m1 = df['a'].str[2:4].eq('20')
m2 = df['a'].str.extract('date_(.*)', expand=False).str[2:4].eq('20')

df = df[m1 | m2]
print (df)
                   a     b
1  abc_def date_1220  john
2      2020124832852  mark
```

EDIT:

```
m2 = df['a'].str.split('_', n=2).str[2].str[2:4].eq('20')
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Made an edit if str contains 20, but not in required position

Comment: @Zanthoxylumpiperitum - What is requred position here?

Comment: 20`20`124832852 and abc_def date_12`20`_abc20

Comment: @Zanthoxylumpiperitum - it means 3,4 letter or last 2 letters?

Comment: 3,4 letter after date_

Comment: Thanks it worked. But instead of `date_`. How can I extract data after second `_`

Answer (score 0):

you can use a list comprehension to get the wanted rows but you have to specify the required positions:

```
import re

req_pos = {2, 15}
df[[any(e.start() in req_pos for e in re.finditer('20', s)) for s in df.a]]
```

[image]

Comment: But instead of starting at 15. How can I extract data after second  under scroll `_`

Comment: @Zanthoxylumpiperitum you can use `str.split('_', 2)[-1]`